# "Keyword not supported: " error in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

i get a Keyword not supported: '192.168.1.1;initial catalog'. error when trying to do this

`Dim cn As New SqlConnection(str)`

where str is the connection string starts with '192.168.1.1;initial catalog' ...
I have not specified the provider in the connection string

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you need to provide a properly formatted connectionstring such as:

```
Dim str As String
str = "Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"

Dim cn As New SqlConnection(str)
```

Comment: Also make sure to remove any extra white-space or formatting.
When I hit enter between "Initial" and "Catalog" I got the same error.

Comment: I got the above error in entirely different context but solution was the connection string. I put ID =xyz instead of User ID = xyz.

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the database with the keyword "Data Source" or "Server".  Here's an example:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```